# STM Analog Output

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

Is it possible to use STM32F4 GPIO pin as analog output? 
As I read, analog mode is an input mode so is there any way, something similar to Arduino's analogWrite

Comment: Did you check the datasheet?

Comment: Did you look into what `analogWrite()` is actually doing on Arduinos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arduino "analog out" is actual a pulse width modulated digital signal, which when *externally averaged* (electrically, mechanically, or via human perception) can be effectively analog for some purposes.

The STM32 series have numerous counter channels which can be used for hardware PWM.  It is not available on every last GPIO, but it is available on many of them - see the programmer's reference manual for the specific part of your interest as the peripheral architecture varies a bit across the family.

You can also attempt software PWM using a timer interrupt.  This will of course have a lower maximum rate, may have some jitter, and will take time away from your ability to accomplish other things.  However these processors have much higher internal clock rates (up to 160 MHz for some F4's) than an ATmega-based Arduino, so this may be a realistic option for you.

As Arsenal mentioned, some *but by no means all* STM32 parts have an actual digital-to-analog converter output (especially the analog variants of the F3 series), but PWM is an option on all parts.

Answer (score 3):

Analog mode can also be used as analog output in conjunction with the 12-bit DAC peripheral:

> Note: Once the DAC channelx is enabled, the corresponding GPIO pin (PA4 or PA5) is
>   automatically connected to the analog converter output (DAC_OUTx). In order to avoid
>   parasitic consumption, the PA4 or PA5 pin should first be configured to analog (AIN).

(as seen in the reference manual in the DAC chapter)

Note: Not all STM32F4 come with the DAC, so on some chips it won't be possible to directly output an arbitrary analog voltage. See the devices datasheet to check which peripherals are available to you.

Comment: Ok, but do you know if analogWrite  on Arduino is similar to PWM on STM? i read that this is pure PWM, but i have doubts. You see, i just bought a DC driver, and in datasheet it says that in order to set speed, i have to enable DC channel and then set value from 0 to 255, 0 is the min speed, 255 is the max. In the sample code they just use Arduino's analogWrite() function and as i understand this is simple PWM wave. So if i want to play with this driver on STM do i have to use DAC or just PWM to achieve this 0-255 values? What do you think? Greets

Comment: @KarolŻurowski I have no experience with Arduino - if analogWrite outputs a PWM, it's quite the misleading name. I suppose there is some sort of RC filter behind it to get it to an analog voltage. You can do that with a STM32 as well. I don't follow you on your DC driver datasheet and DC channel thing though - without knowing the datasheet I'm not going to guess.

Comment: I see. And with STM i have to physically build this RC filter or is it avaliable directly from DISCO board?

Comment: @KarolŻurowski if you go the PWM route, you have to build the RC filter yourself. If you use the DAC route, you don't need a RC filter as the DAC will output the analog voltage which you would have behind the RC filter directly at the pin.

Answer (score 1):

As said above analogWrite from Arduino is actually PWM. You can see an example of PWM code for STM32F4 [here](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/05/stm32f4-stm32f429-discovery-pwm-tutorial/).

You can also try one of the development boards that have DACs, like these one [NUCLEO-F401RE](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a DAC on the STM32F4, or at least the ones I've used.  The way to use it is to write C-code to drive it.  It is somewhat similar in appearance to Arduino's analog write, be that is PWM and not analog.  You would have to learn something new to go from one platform to the other.